# Validating with wtforms - Checking for existing record in MongoDB collection

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying an app with Flask and Mongodb.
I use WTForms and Flask-login, and I'm currently validating the username against duplicates when I sign up using this method:

```
def validate_username(self, username):
    user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": username.data})
    if user:
        raise ValidationError("The username already exists.")
```

And I add the second line when I edit my user, since I am using `flask-login` and I am `current_user`:

```
def validate_username(self, username):
    if username.data != current_user.username:
        user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": username.data})
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("The username already exists.")
```

All this works great, but I also want to validate another field from another form, which is not present in flask-login, of course. This works well when I create the `typeName`:

```
def validate_type_name(self, type_name):
    typeName = mongo.db.types.find_one({"type_name": type_name.data})
    if typeName:
        raise ValidationError("The type name already exists.")
```

But: how could I check for duplicates when I `EDIT` the `typeName`?
What's the magic method that checks in the second line of my function? Or what's the way?

This is my `edit_type` route:

```
@app.route("/type/edit/<id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def edit_type(id):
    form = EditTypeForm()
    type = mongo.db.types.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if current_user.is_admin:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_value = {
                "$set": {
                    "type_name": form.type_name.data,
                    "description": form.description.data,
                }
            }
            mongo.db.types.update_one(type, new_value)
            flash("Type has been updated", "info")
            return redirect(url_for("type", id=type["_id"]))
        elif request.method == "GET":
            form.type_name.data = type["type_name"]
            form.description.data = type["description"]
    return render_template("edit_type.html", title="Edit Type", form=form)
```

Please, help?

Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand what you want to do? When you are editing your typename, should it show duplicate as soon as you are editing like a dropdown? As I see that you already found how to find duplicate with `typeName`.

Comment: I get a validation error when I try to create an existing typeName, but need a way to check for duplicates when I edit it also. I just updated my question adding the route editing it.

Comment: Basically, the relationship between 'create' and 'edit' in the first two snippets, that's what I want to find for my third snippet and a fourth (that I don't have yet!).

Comment: So, you are looking for database to already tell that a user exists before you send the form and then you get validation error.

Comment: Yes, and that's fine for the username because flask-login has that username in current_user, so I can compare current_user with username.data. Now I need to find a validation method for typeName, which is not 'logged in", as it's not an user.

Comment: I can see in the route 'create typeName" if that typeName is in the database, but how to check for it when I am using the route I posted in my update to edit it (update it)? I need to check if that typeName doesn't exist in the database ONLY after checking first if it is not the same I currently have. Basically I should allow to edit the type name and re-use that typeName (Imagine I'm not updating the typeName but just the description)

Comment: To summarise: I need to raise the validation error only when the name already exists in the database AND is different than the one I am already using.

Comment: So just to clarify, you use edit_type because you know that a type_name already exists, if it already exists then you want to edit that type_name, and `id` is the mongoid of the `type`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That collection has two fields: type_name and description. I could decide to edit just the description, but leave the type_name the same. I want to be able to do that, and still need a validation error in case I do change the type_name and type one already existing elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved by adding a hidden field to the form and assigning it the same value as the one currently in the database. Then in the validator there's something to check against.
Full answer here:

[Check duplication when edit an exist database field with WTForms custom validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896450/check-duplication-when-edit-an-exist-database-field-with-wtforms-custom-validato)

Answer (score -1):

In order to make changes where you can only edit the description and leave the type name same and give you an error if the new type name already exists, you can use the function `validate_type_name`.

```
def validate_type_name(self, type_name):
    typeName = mongo.db.types.find_one({"type_name": type_name.data})
    if typeName:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

and then making your edit_type :

```
@app.route("/type/edit/<id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def edit_type(id):
    form = EditTypeForm()
    type = mongo.db.types.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if current_user.is_admin:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_value = {
                "$set": {
                    "type_name": form.type_name.data,
                    "description": form.description.data,
                }
            }
            if not mongo.db.types.find_one({"type_name": form.type_name.data}):
               mongo.db.types.update_one(type, new_value)
               flash("Type has been updated", "info")
               return redirect(url_for("type", id=type["_id"]))
            else:
               <Write validation error message here>
        elif request.method == "GET":
            form.type_name.data = type["type_name"]
            form.description.data = type["description"]
    return render_template("edit_type.html", title="Edit Type", form=form)
```

Comment: Let me try to figure this out. My function vlidate_type_name is in my forms.py file, and is part of my class EditTypeForm(FlaskForm). Let me quickly update my question to be clear, and I of course thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can still call mongo query in if statement, You can check types already has form.type_name.data, this will give you validation error if it already exists. I changed my if statement to check for type_name in database.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid I cannot make this work. I can update my question with my current situation if you think that would help.

Comment: I just updated to the current situation. Hope you could have a bit more patience and help me :)

Comment: By the way, I would rather not have a flash error, but a validation error from wtforms.validators

Comment: I mean, such as using 'raise ValidationError()'