# Check duplication when edit an exist database field with WTForms custom validator

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm having this form with this validator for uniqueness:

```
class CreateTypeForm(FlaskForm):
    type_name = StringField("Type", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description")
    submit = SubmitField("Create")

    def validate_type_name(self, type_name):
        typeName = mongo.db.types.find_one({"type_name": type_name.data})
        if typeName:
            raise ValidationError("The type already exists.")
```

But need to alter the validator for the form I have when I edit my `type`:

```
class EditTypeForm(FlaskForm):
    type_name = StringField("Type", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description")
    submit = SubmitField("Update")
```

So it checks for duplicates but allowing me to keep my current `type_name` if I were to edit only the description and not the name.
What's the way to do this?

In short, how to check the duplication of the type name but also allow saving the original type name?

UPDATE:

Following the gentle advice from the answer below, I have now in my form:

```
class EditTypeForm(FlaskForm):
    origin_type_name = HiddenField()
    type_name = StringField("Type", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description")
    submit = SubmitField("Update")

    def validate_type_name(self, type_name):
        typeName = mongo.db.types.find_one({"type_name": type_name.data})
        if typeName and type_name.data != self.origin_type_name.data:
            raise ValidationError("The type already exists.")
```

And in the route:

```
@app.route("/type/edit/<id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def edit_type(id):
    form = EditTypeForm()
    query = mongo.db.types.find_one(
        {"_id": ObjectId(id)}, {"_id": 0, "type_name": 1}
    )
    current_type_name = query['type_name']
    form.origin_type_name.data = current_type_name
    (etc...)
```

This is now working perfectly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are better solutions, but I got this one:

1. Store the origin type name in a hidden field, then check it in custom validator:

```
class EditTypeForm(FlaskForm):
    origin_type_name = HiddenField()  # import HiddenField first
    type_name = StringField("Type", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description")
    submit = SubmitField("Create")

    def validate_type_name(self, type_name):
        typeName = mongo.db.types.find_one({"type_name": type_name.data})
        if typeName and type_name.data != self.origin_type_name.data:
            raise ValidationError("The type already exists.")
```

2. Set the origin type name in view function before the template rendered:

```
form = EditTypeForm()
form.origin_type_name.data = the_origin_data_get_from_database
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Let me see if I'm interpreting well, because so far I cannot make it work. I updated my question with my current situation and I’m unsure about part 2 of your answer. I'm sure you will spot the error much quicker than me!! :)

Comment: Oh! I think I got it working! I just added `.data` when I assign the hidden field the same value as the current field!

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `.data` :P

Comment: Perhaps if this question helps others as much as it did me, consider using a placeholder name different than the_origin_type_name in the last line because it’s very similar to the name of the hidden field. 
Again, thanks SO much for this clever approach! I would have never come up with this! 